# Rails nested ressources - missing required keys: [:entry_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, has-many, belongs-to

I have two models:

```
    class Credit < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :entries, -> { order(position: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
    end


    class Entry < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :credit
     acts_as_list scope: :credit
    end
```

Using the acts_as_list gem I want to update the order of entries (entry.position) within the view of a credit.

I am using the following setup:

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  devise_for :users
  resources :credits do
    resources :entries
    patch '/entries/:entry_id/update_position', to: 'entries#update_position', as: 'update_position'
  end
  get 'render/index'
  root 'render#index'
end
```

entries_controller.rb (update_position action)

```
     def update_position
      @entry.find(params[:id])
      @entry.insert_at(entry_params[:position].to_i)
      head :ok
     end
```

Under the credits/show I am rendering the respective entries of that credit and want to call the credit_update_position_path to insert the new position.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <%= render @credit %>
        <%= render partial: "entries/form", locals: { entry: @entry } %>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <ul 
        data-controller="sortable" 
        data-sortable-resource-name-value="entry"
        data-sortable-handle-value=".card">
        <% @credit.entries.each do | entry | %>
          <li 
            class="card" 
            data-sortable-update-url="<%= credit_update_position_path(@credit,entry.id) %>">

            <div class="card-body">
              <%= entry.name %>
              <%= entry.id %>
            </div>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
          <div class="credits">
            <% @credit.entries.each do |entry| %>
              <%= entry.name %> 
              <%= entry.id %> 
              <%= entry.role %><br>
            <% end %>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <%= link_to "Back to credits", credits_path %>
    <%= button_to "Destroy this credit", @credit, method: :delete %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the follwoing error when trying to open the show for a credit (in this case @credit_id=7)

```
No route matches {:action=>"update_position", :controller=>"entries", :credit_id=>"7", :entry_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:entry_id]
```

I do have access to the entry.id if I invoke it not as part of the path as you can see in the later part of the code. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: When you implicitly pass the record like this Rails thinks you're passing it as the id placeholder. If you really want this route layout you would use 
`credit_update_position_path(@credit, entry_id: entry.id)`

Comment: tanks, I tried this and unfortunately it still gives me the following error: Showing /workspace/endcreditor/app/views/credits/show.html.erb where line #17 raised:

```No route matches {:action=>"update_position", :controller=>"entries", :credit_id=>#<Credit id: 7, name: "Die Wallnacht", user_id: 2, created_at: "2023-03-29 10:11:40.325533000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-03-29 10:11:40.325533000 +0000">, :entry_id=>nil, :id=>"7"}, possible unmatched constraints: [:entry_id]
Did you mean?  credit_update_position_url```